# AWS EC2 instance not connecting to Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

I am trying to connect AWS EC2 instance to jenkins server but the public ip address is not loading.
i have also added inbound rules on port 8080 but the problem is same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdcWl.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ooKp.png)

I  added security group in inbound rules but the problem is same

Comment: Does the subnet have enough IP addresses left to assign?

Answer (score 0):

- Verify your Jenkins is running on EC2 using the below command

  ```
  systemctl status jenkins
  ```
- if your Jenkins is running hope you are accessing with URL:

  ```
  http://<public_ip:8080
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- Verify your Jenkins is running on EC2

  `systemctl status jenkins`
- Then try allowing all traffic in the security group inbound rule and check.
- Try restarting the Jenkins `systemctl restart jenkins`